# Unable to create an Application - no accounts listed in dashed rectangle beside the Accounts heading

Tags: spinnaker

I am working off the Spinnaker [Getting Started](http://spinnaker.io/documentation/getting_started.html) guide. Spinnaker is now running on an EC2 instance and accessible via http://localhost:9000.

When I try to create a new Application I understand that expect `my-aws-account` and `my-google-account`options. I am however seeing no options on this screen. Any idea about what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 10):

1. Create an AWS User account for Spinnaker

   1. In AWS Console, open AWS Identity & Access Management -> Users -> Create New Users.
   2. Enter a username and hit Create.
   3. Create an access key for the user.
   4. Click Download Credentials, you will need them later.
   5. Click Close.
2. Apply permissions to the new user

   1. Click on the username you entered for a more detailed screen.
   2. On the Summary page, click on the Permissions tab.
   3. Attach a managed policy

      1. Click Attach Policy.
      2. Click the checkbox next to PowerUserAccess, then click Attach Policy.
   4. Create an Inline Policy

      1. Click on the Inline Policies header, then click the link to create an inline policy.
      2. Click Select for Policy Generator.
      3. Select AWS Identity and Access Management from the AWS Service pulldown.
      4. Select PassRole for Actions.
      5. Type `*` (the asterisk character) in the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) box.
      6. Click Add Statement, then Next Step.
      7. Click Apply Policy.
3. Add AWS credentials to Spinnaker

   1. Connect to the Spinnaker instance (I'm assuming you're using Linux)
   2. Run the command: `sudo mkdir /home/spinnaker/.aws`
   3. Run the command: `sudo vim /home/spinnaker/.aws/credentials`
   4. Add the following lines to the file, then save and quit:

      - Make sure to replace `my-aws-account` to the name of your AWS account
      - Make sure to replace the values of the key ID and access key with the credentials you downloaded in Step 1, Part 4

> ```
>    [my-aws-account]
>    aws_access_key_id = AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
>    aws_secret_access_key = wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
> ```

4. Update the default Spinnaker configuration files

   1. Run the command: `sudo vi /etc/default/spinnaker`
   2. Locate the line `SPINNAKER_AWS_ENABLED`, and change the value to `true`
   3. Locate the line `SPINNAKER_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, and change the value to the region where your Spinnaker instance runs (e.g. `us-east-1`, without the quotes)
   4. Save and quit
5. Update the local Spinnaker configuration files (these override the stock YAML files that come with the installation of Spinnaker)

   1. Run the command: `sudo vim /opt/spinnaker/config/spinnaker-local.yml`
   2. Locate `providers`, then locate `aws` beneath that
   3. Beneath `aws`, locate `enabled` and change the value to `true`
   4. Beneath `aws`, locate `defaultRegion` and change the value to the region where your Spinnaker instance runs (e.g. `us-east-1`, without the quotes)
   5. Beneath `primaryCredentials`, locate `name` and change the value to `my-aws-account`

      - Make sure to replace `my-aws-account` to the name of your AWS account
   6. Save and quit
6. Restart Spinnaker

   1. Run the command: `sudo /opt/spinnaker/scripts/reconfigure_spinnaker.sh`
   2. Run the command: `sudo restart spinnaker`
7. Reset the tunnel from your local machine to the Spinnaker instance

Comment: what was the spinnaker version of this?