# Creating application using Spinnaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker

Using `Spinnaker-Ubuntu-14.04-42 (ami-cfb87eaf)` AMI I have created an instance. I have followed the instructions given at [here](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/creating-a-spinnaker-instance). Though my UI works, but when I click `Actions` and `Create Application` the `New Application` popup seems to take lot of time and it does not finish.  What could be a problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution to the problem, by following the instructions given at following links:

1. [Troubleshooting guide](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/troubleshooting-guide), by looking at the Javascript, I figured that the problem is caused due to the credentials of AWS account/user. The error was `429 Too Many Requests`.
2. Then following the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788034/unable-to-create-an-application-no-accounts-listed-in-dashed-rectangle-beside), especially bulleted point 3, I was able to start the application.

Answer (score 0):

When I was getting this. I found I actually needed to use a bigger sized instance. Try using one with more memory.