# No account/vpc available when trying to create security group

Tags: spinnaker

I've installed Spinnaker on AWS using the quick start guide (https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/spinnaker/latest/doc/spinnaker-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf). I'm now going through the bake/deploy (http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/bake-and-deploy-pipeline) guide.

I'm trying to create a security group for my application, but there is nothing to select in the Account field. Also, the VPC field only shows None (EC2 Classic). What am I missing?

Tried this answer, but no luck: [Unable to create an Application - no accounts listed in dashed rectangle beside the Accounts heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788034/unable-to-create-an-application-no-accounts-listed-in-dashed-rectangle-beside)

Answer (score 0):

Spinnaker follows some very specific [naming conventions for VPCs](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/troubleshooting-guide#section-i-don-t-see-my-vpcs-in-any-of-the-dropdowns-). If these are existing VPCs/subnets, and you're not seeing anything in the VPC select field (assuming you're not seeing it when trying to create load balancers or server groups, too), you can add a tag to the VPC and its subnets via the AWS console with the key `immutable_metadata` and the value: `{"purpose": "{subnet purpose}"}`

Comment: I had checked that as well. The CF template spun up a VPC and added what looks like the correct subnet tagging: ie: vpc-60676106.internal.us-east-1a. Does the VPC itself need a special tag? I'm wondering if it is getting tripped up because I had a pre-existing VPC also in the account? etc/default/spinnaker has the correct vpc id specified

Answer (score 0):

The CF template from the quickstart names the vpc 'SpinnakerVPC' and the subnets SpinnakerVPC.internal.{az}. When i renamed the vpc to 'defaultvpc' and updated the subnet names to 'defaultvpc.internal.{az} and restarted i can now see my VPC's.

Answer (score 0):

VPC need to have tag in the following format "{vpcName}.{subnetPurpose (e.g. "internal")}.{availabilityZone}". I am using my existing VPC and there I had to add tag "immutable_metadata = {"purpose": "{TestDeploy}"}" for VPC.
Also, make sure Subnet names are in the following format
"{VPC Name}.{external or internal}.{az}.
Make sure re-start the Spinnaker and refresh the case.
See the link for more detail information,
http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/troubleshooting-guide